# Create new file in /etc without overriding existing files

Tags: linux, debian, symbolic-link

Is it possible to create a new file in `/etc` without overriding some of the existing files?

I need to add something to `/etc/fstab` but would rather create a new file where I can add my custom configurations

Is it possible to create a file to something like `/etc/fstab0` that would extend `/etc/fstab` ??

Comment: Why don't you just copy `/etc/fstab` to `/etc/fstab0`, so that you have the original file that you can revert to? I don't see the point of creating a symbolic link.

Comment: I want the possibility to "install" or "uninstall" my application multiple times without overriding the default config

Comment: You simply add entries to the end of the table. If you're doing this by a script, then you need to allow for script errors which might corrupt `fstab`, but I still don't see the advantage of a link, unless you want to keep several different copies which you can easily switch between.

Answer (score 0):

You can add entries to /etc/fstab and comment them out or in. Like this:

```
/dev/sda1   /    ext4   relatime,errors=remount-ro    0  1
/dev/sda5   none swap   sw                            0  0
#/dev/sda2  /foo ext4   none                          0  0
```

You can comment the last line out only when you need it, thus leaving "the default" functionally unmodified.

To directly answer your question: no you can not use an "alternative" fstab file - you would have to change how the system boots itself to be able to do that. However some systems support a /etc/fstab.d directory where you can add **additional** fstab files. I do not know much about that, you'll need to duckduckgo it.

Answer (score 0):

For some applications you can do this, for others you can't.  FSTAB is one of those you can't do this for.  (There was talk about including this functionality at some stage a few years back, but this was reverted)

As an alternative measure you might be able to use [systemd mounts](https://blog.fpmurphy.com/2014/04/system-d-and-etcfstab.html) to get the desired functionality (ie files within systemd space ending in .mount with appropriate lines - although this is not something I have explored in any detail.